# Connecting to a public FTP behind a corporate proxy

Tags: python, ftp

I'm trying to access a public FTP in my work, but I'm getting an error.

That's is the code that I used in my house.

```
from ftplib import FTP

ftp = FTP('ftp.cetip.com.br')
ftp.login()
ftp.cwd('/MediaCDI')
ftp.quit()
```

It's work fine in my home, but in my work I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TBMEPYG\Desktop\stack.py", line 3, in <module>
    ftp = FTP('ftp.cetip.com.br')
  File "C:\Users\TBMEPYG\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\ftplib.py", line 117, in __init__
    self.connect(host)
  File "C:\Users\TBMEPYG\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\ftplib.py", line 152, in connect
    source_address=self.source_address)
  File "C:\Users\TBMEPYG\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 722, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\TBMEPYG\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)

[Finished in 21.3s]
```

When I was developing a **scraper** in a HTTP website, I solved this problem for http using HTTPProxyAuth and requests. Just to illustrate, that's was the code:

```
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth
import requests

user = 'xxxx'
password = 'yyyy'

credenciais = HTTPProxyAuth(user, password)
params = {'Dt_Ref': data, 'TpInstFinanceiro': 'CRI', 'Tipo':'1','saida':'txt'}
proxy_access = {'http':'proxy.mywork/accelerated_pac_base.pac'}
url = 'http://www.anbima.com.br/reune/reune_down.asp'


r = requests.post(url, data = params, proxies = proxy_access , auth = credenciais)
```

Anyone has any idea about what can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Ask your IT department for FTP access?

Comment: It's possible to connect using chrome , but I can't access using python